# Null Reference Exception for Class Lists

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am new to programming and am running into an issue when creating a class with a list property of another class and then accessing it in main. I am getting the exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" after trying to Add an item to the list I get this error during runtime. I do understand that the List<> reference is null but am trying to understand why it is null and how to get around it. My code will function properly if I just create the List in main but I would like to have it as a class in the future. Like I said I am new to programming OOP and trying to get some information regarding why this is happening. I apologize if this is a repeat question. My code snippet is below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BookList myBookList = new BookList();

        myBookList.bookList.Add(new Book("The Giver", "Lois Lowry", "Houghton Mifflin"));
        myBookList.bookList.Add(new Book("Telling Lies", "Paul Ekman", "Norton & Company"));
    }


class BookList
{
    public List<Book> bookList { get; set; }
}

class Book
{
    public Book(string title, string author, string publisher)
    {
        Title = title;
        Author = author;
        Publisher = publisher;
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }        
}
```

Thank you, I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create `BookList`, you haven't actually initialized the list that is its member. You can do this by changing your initialization to:

```
BookList myBookList = new BookList() {bookList = new List<Book>()};
```

Or by writing a constructor for the `BookList` class which initializes the list; which would look like this:

```
class BookList
{
    public List<Book> bookList { get; set; }

    public BookList(){ //New constructor
        bookList = new List<Book>();
    }
}
```

The reason you get this error is that while you've created an instance of BookList, you haven't actually make sure that the `BookList`'s inner `booklist` property is initialized. It's like if you tried to do this:

```
List<string> newList;
newList.Add("foo");
```

That wouldn't work because you've only declared the `newList`, not initialized it.

Comment: I would highly recommend putting the bookList = new List<Book> on a separate line...

Comment: @Steve In general I tend to only put them on newlines when there are multiple properties to initialize, just my code style (I really like one-liners). If you want you can put the list initialization on a new line.

Comment: Perfect, thank you sir, this fixed my issues. Also thank you for the explaination

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `Boolist.bookList` in the `default ctor`:

```
class BookList
{
    public BookList() { bookList = new List<Book>; } // <<<<
    public List<Book> bookList { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `public List<Book> bookList { get; set; }` in  your `BookList` class; you've never initialized it.  You can do this, for example, from within the constructor:

```
class BookList
{
    public List<Book> bookList { get; set; }

    public BookList
    {
        bookList = new List<Book>();
    }
}
```

Please note: properties should always be named with Pascal casing, i.e. all letters uppercase:  `BookList` not `bookList`.

Also, since it doesn't really make sense to *replace* your `BookList` with another instance of `List<Book>`, I would suggest you set the access modifier on the setter to `private` so it can only be initialized once, i.e. in the constructor:

```
public List<Book> bookList { get; private set; } // notice the "private" set
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed my problem! Also, thank you for the tip on the access modifier, I am just starting to truly understand their purpose. Its better to do this initialization in the class versus doing it in the main correct?

Comment: That depends.  The answer can get complicated (dependency injection, inversion of control, etc.); it largely depends on your needs.

Comment: @Calskiez, in general it's good to do it in the class initialization, but there are other times when you'll want to initialize such properties with values other than what the class provides. You can either provide separate ctors for such cases or you can initialize the property at the time of 'new'ing the class using the `{ prop = value, ... }` syntax as described in Christ H's answer.