# What is the effective way to store objects for a class?

Tags: c#, oop, constructor, dispose

For example I have a class like as below. And I need to store all objects to it and need to Dispose it whenever required.

```
public class SendPeriodicTelemetry : IDisposable
{
   public List<SendPeriodicTelemetry> SendPeriodicTelemetryObjs { get; set; }
   
    public SendPeriodicTelemetry()
    {
        SendPeriodicTelemetryObjs.Add(this);
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {            
        foreach (var obj in SendPeriodicTelemetryObjs)
        {                
            obj.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

But for the above code as soon as I instantiate an object for 'SendPeriodicTelemetry' get error as below

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This class object is invoked from another class as below

```
public static class PublisherClass
    {
         public static async Task PublishToMethod(string methodName, string message)
        {
            try
            {                          
                switch (methodName)
                {
                    case "start":
                    case "stop":                        
                        var sendperObj = new SendPeriodicTelemetry();
                        sendperObj.aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();                        
                        if (methodName == "start")
                        {                            
                           
                        }
                        else
                        {                           
                          <"Clear All the SendPeriodicTelemetry instances active">
                        }
                        break;                  
                }
            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception occurred {exception.ToString()}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here my requirement is whenever 'start' method is called it creates new instance of '**SendPeriodicTelemetry**' every time.
And when 'stop' method is invoked I need to clear all the '**SendPeriodicTelemetry**' instances. I thought of invoking manually through invoking **'Dispose()'** when *stop* is called. If any other better option is there please suggest.Thanks

Comment: You never create an actual `List` object using `new List<SendPeriodicTelemetry>`

Comment: why would you add *yourself* to your own list...? what are you trying to *do* here? can you clarify? (the problem in the code is simply: not creating the list in the first place, which is best fixed as `public List<SendPeriodicTelemetry> SendPeriodicTelemetryObjs { get; } = new List<SendPeriodicTelemetry>();` - but: I wonder if the code is trying to do something more... *more* here; also: the `Dispose()` here will loop forever, precisely *because* `this` is in the list; disposing X loops over the list, calling dispose on each... one of which is X - and boom: `StackOverflowException`)

Comment: You declare `<List>` on a class and you call that `<List>` on another class by `<List>SendPeriodicTelemetry spt = new <List>SendPeriodicTelemetry` Are you trying to perform such action? Else try to read comment from **Marc Gravell**, Moreover, where you want to get data from (store to the object), you have to let the fellas know what you are trying to do so that they can offer you an effective way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510963/null-reference-exception-for-class-lists/38511001

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for your insights. I have updated the question with more details. Please let me know if you require any further details.

Comment: @Lawraoke I updated my question with more details. Please let me know it helps

Comment: Anyway i achieved my objective. But it's just about disposing the System.Timers.Timer instances which the events are subscribed too. So as per my original question it's not required to dispose the instances to achieve my requirement. But the question can remain to know about disposing the instances for a class.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the proper way [to implement `IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#examples). **Note that** this Provides a mechanism for *releasing unmanaged resources*. This is not necessary for managed code. So leave it to the garbage collector and you may need to clarify in your post why you are implementing `IDisposable`.

**Considering that** the `foreach` statement will do nothing with the elements in the list. you cannot `dispose` a list since it isn't `IDisposable` or force it to be collected.

If you want to implement `IDisposable` you must make sure that the code using your class either instantiates inside a `using()` statement or manually calls `.Dispose`. Otherwise your dispose method will never fire.

```
using(var SendPeriodicTelemetry = new SendPeriodicTelemetry()){
    // Do something with SendPeriodicTelemetry 
    // SendPeriodicTelemetry.Dispose() is called automatically when you exit this using statement.
}
```