# what is difference between public class object=new class() and public class object{get;set;}

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, mode

what is difference between public `class object=new class()` and `public class object{get;set;}`.

when i am trying to `public ProviderPInfo obj = new ProviderPInfo();` it is workig perfectly but
when i am trying to this `public ProviderPInfo providerpersonalinfo { get; set;}` it gives me:

> `System.NullReferenceException`: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**

**model class:**

```
public class ProviderPInfo
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> UserType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Status { get; set; }
}
```

**class where object is instentiate;**

```
public class provider {
    public ProviderPInfo obj = new ProviderPInfo();
    public ProviderPInfo providerpersonalinfo { get; set;}      
}
```

code where data is getting;

```
List<User> objList = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserType == 50).ToList();
     
        List<provider> retObj = new List<provider>();
        foreach (var item in objList)
        {
            provider obj = new provider();
          
            //obj.providerpersonalinfo=
            try
            {
                //string a = item.FirstName;

                obj.obj.Email = item.Email;
                obj.obj.UserID = item.UserID;
                obj.obj.FirstName = item.FirstName;
                obj.obj.LastName = item.LastName;
                obj.obj.PhoneNumber = item.PhoneNumber;
                obj.obj.Address = item.Address;
                obj.obj.City = item.City;
                obj.obj.State = item.State;
                obj.obj.ZipCode = item.ZipCode;
                obj.obj.MobilePhone = item.MobilePhone;
                obj.obj.UserType = item.UserType;
                obj.obj.Status = item.Status;
                //obj.providerpersonalinfo.LastName = item.LastName;
                //obj.providerpersonalinfo.Email = item.Email;
                //obj.providerpersonalinfo.UserID = item.UserID;
                //obj.providerpersonalinfo.PhoneNumber = item.PhoneNumber;
                //obj.providerpersonalinfo.Address = item.Address;
                //obj.providerpersonalinfo.City = item.City;
                //obj.providerpersonalinfo.State = item.State;
                //obj.providerpersonalinfo.ZipCode = item.ZipCode;
                //obj.providerpersonalinfo.MobilePhone = item.MobilePhone;
                //obj.providerpersonalinfo.UserType = item.UserType;
                //obj.providerpersonalinfo.Status = item.Status;
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
```

Comment: Also see: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Also see: [Null Reference Exception for Class Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510963/null-reference-exception-for-class-lists/38511001)

Answer (score 0):

```
public ProviderPInfo providerpersonalinfo { get; set;}
```

**Respect then Encapsulation principle.**

Technically in encapsulation, the variables or data of a class are hidden from any other class and can be accessed only through any member function of own class in which they are declared.

for example you can

```
public ProviderPInfo providerpersonalinfo { get; private set;}
```

Pratically in POCO Classes there is no difference.

providerpersonalinfo is null in the beginning,  you can assign in constructor or like this.

```
public ProviderPInfo providerpersonalinfo { get; set;}=new ProviderPInfo();
```